# MYSQL query for first 40 records and else records

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

I have a table names 'tbl_featured_professional' where fields are:

```
id,
user_id,
ranking and 
score,
createdDate
```

What I want is first 40 records are ordered from ranking (which is unique) and all other records after 40 which are ordered by score. I want to do it from mysql and not from PHP. How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ranking -- as its name implies -- is a number starting at 1 and incrementing, then:

```
select fp.*
from tbl_featured_professional fp
order by (fp.ranking <= 40) desc,
         (case when fp.ranking <= 40 then ranking end),
         score;
```

Answer (score 0):

check my solution

```
select * from 
(
  select * from tbl_featured_professional
  order by ranking
  limit 40
)
union all
select * from 
(
  select * from tbl_featured_professional
  order by score
  limit 9999999 offset 40
)
```

Comment: Would the `offset 40` in the second part of the query be the offset when ordered by `score`, which may be different to the first 40 ordered by `ranking`

Comment: I couldn't understand. It is `limit 9999999 offset 40`. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: The offset in the second query will be based on the order by for that query, so it will only return rows from the 40th row sorted by score.  The first query returns the first 40 rows ordered by ranking.  So rows sorted by score and ranking may be in a different order.

Comment: I would also say that *check my solution* isn't a particularly good explanation of what your answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Using with 2 sub-queries along with `UNION ALL` and `NOT IN` should work for you.
The first query will select the 40 rows ordered by `ranking`, the second query with sub-query will select all the other rows **except** the first 40 rows that are already selected by first sub-query and order it by `score`. The UNION ALL clause will merge these 2 sub-query records as a single set. Hope this helps and understandable :) now.

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_featured_professional ORDER BY ranking LIMIT 40
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM tbl_featured_professional WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM tbl_featured_professional ORDER BY ranking LIMIT 40) 
 ORDER BY score
```

Comment: @NigelRen Sir, Just added some explanation. Hope it is understandable now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 subqueries and `UNION`.
The 1st gets the top 40 that are ordered by `ranking` 
and the 2nd reorders the remaining rows by `score`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_featured_professional
ORDER BY ranking
LIMIT 40
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tbl_featured_professional
    ORDER BY ranking
    LIMIT 40, 18446744073709551615
  )
  ORDER BY score
)
```

`18446744073709551615` = `2^64 - 1`, see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id4651990).